# Literate LINQ-to-XML: Best practice to deserialize attribute/value to structured variable/value pairs

Tags: c#, serialization, linq-to-xml

I'm wrestling to deserialize the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<conf name="settings">

    <item name="lorem"
        one="the"
        two="quick"
        three="brown"
        four="fox"
        five="jumps"
        six="over"
        seven="the"
        eight="lazy"
        nine="dog"
            />

    <item name="ipsum"
        one="how"
        two="many"
        three="roads"
        four="must"
        five="a"
        six="man"
        seven="walk"
        eight="down"
        nine="?"
            />

</conf>
```

hoping to do so in the most elegant and succinct way using LINQ-to-XML, but given that I'm not the smartest kid in town  when it comes to nested methods, infered types, generics, et cétera, I thought it'd be a good idea to ask if any of you guys would like to go ahead and show me some LINQ literacy :)

Right now for every value I'm doing something like:

```
XDocument config = XDocument.Load("whatever.conf");

var one = from q in config.Descendants("item")
            select (string)q.Attribute("one");

var two = from q in config.Descendants("item")
            select (string)q.Attribute("two");
```

And *I do know* I'm totally missing the point, not only because I'm repeating myself a lot there but also because that queries only work when there's only one item so, again if you have any comment or suggestion it would be really appreciated.
Thanks much in advance!

**UPDATE:** in case that perhaps the former example wasn't really helpful, here's a more sort of realistic scenario:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<conf name="ftp-settings" freq="daily" time="23:00">
    <item   name="isis"
            host="10.10.1.250"
            user="jdoe"
            pass="4/cB0kdFGprXR/3oTs8mtw=="
            file="backup.tar.gz"
            path="/var/log"
        />
    <item   name="seth"
            host="10.10.2.250"
            user="jdoe"
            pass="4/cB0kdFGprXR/3oTs8mtw=="
            file="backup.tar.gz"
            path="/var/log"
        />
</conf>
```

Therefore for each of those items I'd like to generate variables so I can pass them as parameters for some FTP management method.

**SOLVED:**

It was as easy as doing a **foreach**:

```
var elements = from element in xml.Descendants("item") select element;

foreach (XElement item in elements) {
    ftp.DownloadFile(
        item.Attribute("host").Value,
        item.Attribute("user").Value,
        item.Attribute("pass").Value,
        item.Attribute("file").Value,
        item.Attribute("path").Value
        );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally I'd expect to want a single representation of each element, rather than one sequence of "one" values and another sequence of "two" values. In other words, I'd expect something like:

```
var items = config.Descendants("item")
                  .Select(element => Item.FromXElement(element));
```

If you have a lot of attributes in a single element, I find it helpful to separate out the "make an object from this element" code into its own method (in this case `Item.FromXElement`) rather than stuff it all into the query. If `Item` shouldn't know about its LINQ to XML representation, put the method somewhere that should :)

`items` is then an `IEnumerable<Item>` which you can convert into a list or whatever else you want to do.

Of course it really depends on what you're trying to do - and we don't really know what this is meant to represent. Maybe you really *do* want each "attribute sequence" separately...

---

`Item.FromXElement` would look something like:

```
public static Item FromXElement(XElement element)
{
    string name = (string) element.Attribute("name");
    string host = (string) element.Attribute("host");
    // etc
    return new Item(name, host, ...);
}
```

(Where obviously you'd create a constructor with the appropriate parameters.)

Comment: First all thanks a lot for your comment Jon! I really need to keep those separate; Imagine I'm persisting, let's say, connection details or, bookmarks, so on, so forth, then it's really up to keeping the *lorem* and *ipsum* elements separate, and then creating key/value pairs out of its attributes. I hope you followed my elaboration, anyhow don't hesitate to ask me for further explanatory efforts :)

Comment: I don't *really* follow the elaboration, no. Could you edit your question to give a fuller example of what you're trying to do and how you want to use the information afterwards?

Comment: I did. Thanks much in advance Jon.

Comment: Right - that looks like each item has a bunch of information which goes together. I'd create appropriate objects with all of it together, and a list of those objects.

Comment: Any idea about how to implement the **Item.FromXElement** serialization magic?

Comment: Just saying, your code has compile error : `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

Comment: Also, is there a more elegant implementation to the FromXElement? Xml.Serialization [has something interesting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364253/how-to-deserialize-xml-document) where the element/attribute names can be declared as a property attribute, IMO this makes the code more readable. Unfortunately this doesn't work with XElement imo

Comment: @LouisRhys: Which line is failing with that error? I've already got explicit conversions for the attributes... Personally I dislike the "automatic" sort of serialization in general. By keeping it explicit, it's really easy to understand and maintain; you can make changes for backwards compatibility (e.g. understanding two different attribute names) etc.

Comment: oops, my Bad.. I forgot to copy the explicit conversion.. I thought defining in attribute was easy to maintain and understand, because the attributes are defined in the same place as the property name, and you can avoid having to define a lot of constants such as `NameAttributeName`, `HostAttributeName`, etc.

Comment: @LouisRhys: They're easy to use *if they just work out of the box* - but as soon as you want some kind of custom behaviour, they become problematic. Also, IIRC, it's hard to write genuinely immutable types using XML serialization.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:

```
XDocument config = XDocument.Load("whatever.conf");

var pairs = from q in config.Descendants("item")
           select new {
               One = (string)q.Attribute("one"),
               Two = (string)q.Attribute("two") };

var ones = pairs.Select(pair => pair.One);
var twos = pairs.Select(pair => pair.Two);
```

Comment: Pavel thanks much for the comment, although what I really need is to have two resulting collections isis and seth, both of them with all its attributes accessible perhaps in the form of isis.host, isis.user, so on.